# Multiple viewport problem

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm setting up so I can switch between either one or four viewports but I got some trouble.

In my bottom right viewport I got camera view, the same camera that I can switch to full view on. The other three viewports are working with fixed locations but the bottom right viewport is compressed on the y scale and half of the picture on the x scale is missing.

```
void display(int what)
{
    if(what==5){glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    ca.lookAt();}

    if(what==1){glViewport(0, 0, w/2, h/2);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(75,15,-5,0,5,-5,0,1,0);}

    if(what==2){glViewport(w/2, h/2, w, h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0,110,0,20,0,20,1,0,0);}

    if(what==3){glViewport(w/2, 0, w, h/2);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45.0f, float(320) / float(240), 0.1f, 100.0f); 
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    ca.lookAt();}

    if(what==4){glViewport(0, h/2, w/2, h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(185,75,25,0,28,0,0,1,0);}


    //glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    //glLoadIdentity();
    ////gluLookAt(cos(shared.time) * shared.distance, 10, sin(shared.time) * shared.distance, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);   // Roterar kameran kring origo genom att skapa en ny vymatris varje bildruta
    ////ca.orbitYaw(0.05);
    //ca.lookAt();

    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    drawScene();
    drawCamera();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void viewport(){
glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);

    if(!divided_view_port)
    {
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    glScissor(0,0,640,480);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45.0f, w / h, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    display(5);
    }

else
{
    ////////////////////// bottom left - working
    glViewport(0, 0, w/2, h/2);
    glScissor(0,0,w/2,h/2);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45.0f, w / h, 0.1f, 300.0f);
    display(1);
    //////////////////////


    ////////////////////// top right - working
    glViewport(w/2, h/2, w, h);
    glScissor(w/2,h/2,w,h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45.0f, w / h, 0.1f, 300.0f);
    display(2);
    //////////////////////

    ////////////////////// bottom right -working
    glViewport(w/2, 0, w, h/2);
    glScissor(w/2,0,w,h/2);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45.0f, w / h, 0.1f, 300.0f);
    display(3);
    ////////////////////////

    ////////////////////////// top left
    glViewport(0, h/2, w/2, h);
    glScissor(0,h/2,w/2,h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45.0f, w / h, 0.1f, 300.0f);
    display(4);
    ///////////////////////////
}

glDisable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
```

Comment: You aren't using proper C++ syntax, and you aren't posting a picture of your problem.

Comment: What's up with your multiple `glViewport()` calls?  You have calls in `viewport()` and then more in `display()`, wiping out whatever `viewport()` may have set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[glViewport()](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glViewport.xml) takes an offset and a *size*.

Your code seems to be passing lower-left and upper-right coordinates.

Try these:

```
glViewport(   0,  0, w/2, h/2);  // lower-left
glViewport(w/2,   0, w/2, h/2);  // lower-right
glViewport(w/2, h/2, w/2, h/2);  // upper-right
glViewport(  0, h/2, w/2, h/2);  // upper-left
```